# Are there any tools to scale/magnify a given window or application?

Tags: windows, scaling, high-dpi, magnifier

I recently purchased a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro, which sports a high-dpi 13" screen with a resolution of 3200x1800, running under Win8.1.

The issue I sometimes face is that some applications will not scale properly and will look tiny on screen, making them almost unusable.

I'm aware of the scaling options for Win8 and of the magnifier tool (that you can call using the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> keys), but it will magnify parts of the screen only and its use is cumbersome since it is indiscriminate.

Ideally, what I would need is a utility that can automatically resize the windows of a given application or at least a selected window.

I'm sure this is an issue that will become more common as high-dpi screens become more mainstream for Windows machines.

Answer (score 2):

Try [ZoomIt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx) from Microsoft SysInternals. I am not sure if it meets your critera but it is definitely a good freeware zooming tool.

Introduction from the tool's website:

> ZoomIt is a screen zoom and annotation tool for technical
>   presentations that include application demonstrations. ZoomIt runs
>   unobtrusively in the tray and activates with customizable hotkeys to
>   zoom in on an area of the screen, move around while zoomed, and draw
>   on the zoomed image. I wrote ZoomIt to fit my specific needs and use
>   it in all my presentations.
>
> ZoomIt works on all versions of Windows and you can use pen input for
>   ZoomIt drawing on tablet PCs.